# Clean up domain list in Excel - regex / macros?

Tags: regex, excel, vba, dns

I have a huge spreadsheet of domains that I need to clean up as follows:

1. Remove all `http://` (simple replace all - "http://" with "")
2. Remove any `www.` (simple replace all - "www." with "")
3. Delete any sub-domains (delete the actual row completely, not just the subdomain from the url)
4. Remove anything after the domain extension (i.e. `website.com/blah/blahbah/` becomes just `website.com` (simple replace all - `"/*"` with `""`, then replace all `"/"` with `""`)

So what I'm left with is just a spreadsheet of clean domains like `"website.com"`.

I think I've got 1, 2 and 4 sorted (as above), **but I'm really struggling with 3**.

Any ideas? Can I do this with [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) / [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), and actually delete the row completely?

**Sample data:**

http://www.scholastic.com/kids/stacks/games/
http://imgworld.teamworkonline.com/
http://topfreegraphics.com/
http://www.workcircle.co.uk/
http://www.healthycanadians.gc.ca/index-eng.php
http://gsociology.icaap.org/methods/soft.html

**Post 1, 2 and 4 would leave me with:**

scholastic.com
imgworld.teamworkonline.com
topfreegraphics.com
workcircle.co.uk
healthycanadians.gc.ca
gsociology.icaap.org

It's those pesky sub-domains I need to just delete completely, just delete the row. I've realised I can't just search for 2 x ".", because obviously plenty of domain extensions (i.e `.co.uk`) include that.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could loop through your data, indeed check for double . and just delete the current row (macro) If you like I could look into it or if you know how that's better!

Comment: If you want concrete help, show us some real data (screeshots for instance) and the expected output and what you've tried so far and what is your question. This way, you will get real and precise answers.

Comment: Sorry chaps, example data added and how I'm achieving what I am up to this point.

Comment: Thanks Tim, much better. Tricky though - unless there is a master list of valid domain extensions somewhere I think your best bet would be to validate likely passes (`.co.xx`,  `.com.xxx` etc) and then list the remainder in the file for manual checking

Comment: Thanks Brett, sounds painful... spreadsheet has 150,000 domains in it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *can* figure out which [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) to use for step three, the following code will do what you need it to do, once you adapt the ranges appropriately.

```
Private Sub xlRegexp()

Dim c As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim strOldText As String
Dim RegExFindThis As String
Dim RegEx
Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

c = 1

WhichCase:

 Select Case c
    Case 1    
        RegExFindThis = "http://"    
    Case 2    
        RegExFindThis = "www."    
    Case 3    
        RegExFindThis = "/.*"    
    Case Else    
        GoTo Subdomains    
End Select

With RegEx
    .Pattern = RegExFindThis
    .Global = True
End With

For n = [X] To [Y]
    Range("A" & n).Activate 'assumes your list is in column A
    strOldText = ActiveCell.Text
    ActiveCell.Value = RegEx.Replace(strOldText, "")
Next

c = c + 1

GoTo WhichCase
Subdomains:

RegExFindThis = "[STEP 3 RegExp]"

With RegEx
    .Pattern = RegExFindThis
    .Global = True
End With

n = 1

For n = [X] To [Y]
    Range("A" & n).Activate 'assumes your list is in column A
    If RegEx.Test(ActiveCell.Text) Then
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next

Set RegEx = Nothing
MsgBox ("Macro complete.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+1)),"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),$D:$D,0)),"Subdomain",""))
```

Column A: list of domains.
Column D: list of accepted subdomain records (gov.uk, etc.), compiled by a user.

Works also for domains, having 3 or more dots.

Subdomain cells can be filtered out and deleted afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Juri this looks good, I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: -he said, 4 years ago

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple approach:

```
for i = worksheet.rows.count to 1 step -1
Dim counter as Integer
Dim Value as String
Dim splitter as String()
Value = worksheet.cells(i,1).value
Dim splitter() As String
splitter=split(Value,".")

if ubound(splitter)>1 then
workseet.rows.removeat(i)
end if
next
```

Will probably not work out of the box, because there where no data to test this, but it should work generally...